# Default params in ngrx getWithQuery()

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I wonder how can send the default data already in `getWithQuery()`, like this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CompaniesDataService extends DefaultDataService<Company> {
    private readonly _URL: string = '/api/companies';
    private readonly _DEFAULT_QUERIES: QueryParams = {top: '0', limit: '10', order: "name"};

    constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator) {
        super('Company', http, httpUrlGenerator);
    }

    getWithQuery(queryParams: QueryParams | string = this._DEFAULT_QUERIES): Observable<Company[]> {
        return this.http
            .post<FmsHttpResponse<Company>>(`${this._URL}/search`, queryParams)
            .pipe(map(response => response.content));
    }
}
```

I mean `this._DEFAULT_QUERIES` pass as default `queryParams` in `getWithQuery()`.

When I add function with resolver like this:

```
    return this.companyEntityService.getWithQuery()
      .pipe(tap(() => this.companyEntityService.setLoaded(true)));
```

I got error: `Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.`.

Any idea? I would like to add that I am a novice ngrx programmer and maybe it is a simple question and I cannot find the answer.

Comment: most likely you haven't save the service file

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have to send something that is already in the class as a parameter? Why not do something like this:

```
 getWithQuery(queryParams: QueryParams | undefined): Observable<Company[]> {
       if(queryParams === undefined){
           queryParams = this._DEFAULT_QUERIES;
       }
        return this.http
            .post<FmsHttpResponse<Company>>(`${this._URL}/search`, queryParams)
            .pipe(map(response => response.content));
    }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. You have to override the `getWithQuery` function somehow

Comment: What do you mean by override? Do you have an error message? As far as i can see, it's a function that is used one or more places. So if you want to force it to use the _DEFAULT_QUERIES you just call it with getWithQuery(undefined)